# QBitArray in Qt Bitwise Operations

Tags: qt

I have a 12-bit register with different hardware peripherals:

`enum HWPeripherals { HW0=0, HW1, HW2, HW3, HW4, HW5, HW6, HW7, HW8, HW9, HW10, HW11 };`

I have an integer response(between 0 and 4095). I have to check the int response against the enum HWPeripherals to check which hardware peripherals are present. I need to implement this in Qt. I came across QBitArray class in Qt on the internet. But having problems when using it in my code.

I know this in plain C++ and needs converting to Qt terms

```
for(int i=0; i<12; i++) //12 because of its a 12bit register//
{
  if(1<<i & value) > 0)
  {
    switch(i)
     {
       case 0:
         //HW0 present//
        break;

       case 1:
         //HW1 present//
        break;

       case 2:
         //HW2 present//
        break;

       //so on....//

       case 11:
         //HW11 present//
        break;
     }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert your code to use `QBitArray` in Qt, you can do the following:

1. Initialize a QBitArray object with the 12-bit register size:

```
QBitArray bits(12);
```

2. Set the bits in the QBitArray based on the int response:

```
bits.fill(false); // initialize all bits to false
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    if(1<<i & value) {
        bits.setBit(i, true);
    }
}
```

3. Check the bits in the QBitArray against the enum HWPeripherals:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    if(bits.testBit(i)) {
        switch(i) {
            case HW0:
                // HW0 present
                break;
            case HW1:
                // HW1 present
                break;
            case HW2:
                // HW2 present
                break;
            // so on...
            case HW11:
                // HW11 present
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The `setBit()` function sets the bit at the given index to true or false, and the [testBit()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbitarray.html#testBit) function returns whether the bit at the given index is true or false. Note that the index of the bit in the QBitArray corresponds to the enum value of the hardware peripheral.